# Multicolumn centering not working with use of paragraph column for wrapped text in tabularx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, multicolumn

I am using a multicolumn at the end of my table to indicate what some of the abbreviations mean. I have enough of them that I need to wrap the text so I am using a paragraph column with centering defined. However, I noticed when I do not use the full textwidth, that the contents of the multicolumn is not centered as I would expect. Any way to fix this? MWE is below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,array,multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{table}[!htbp]
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Characteristics of Patients\label{tab:ptChar}}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{P{0.15\textwidth}
                             >{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}X 
                             >{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}X
                             >{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}X
                             >{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule[1.5pt]
Characteristic & Patients (n=132) & $>$30\% (n=11) & $<$30\% (n=92) & p \\
\midrule

\raggedright Mean Age at Pathologic Diagnosis & 54.8 & 51.6 & 55.1 & 0.47* \\

\raggedright Ethnicity &  &  &  & 1.00\textsuperscript{\#} \\

\raggedright \hangindent=3mm \hangafter=0 Caucasian        & 76 &
 \shortstack{6 \\ (55\%)} & \shortstack{52 \\ (57\%)} & \\

\raggedright \hangindent=3mm \hangafter=0 African American & 45 &
 \shortstack{4 \\ (36\%)} & \shortstack{30 \\ (33\%)} & \\

\raggedright \hangindent=3mm \hangafter=0 NA               & 11 &
 \shortstack{1 \\ (9\%)}  & \shortstack{10 \\ (11\%)} & \\

\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\multicolumn{5}{P{0.8\textwidth}}{sfkdjkjke: lkjdfkljkljflasf; ioawejroias: kjskldfj.asdjf.; pval: p-value; *: Wilcoxon test; \textsuperscript{\#}: Fisher's Exact Test; NA: missing data }\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can vastly simplify your input:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering\footnotesize

\caption{Characteristics of Patients\label{tab:ptChar}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
Characteristic & Patients ($n=132$) & $>30\%$ ($n=11$) & $<30\%$ ($n=92$) & p \\
\midrule

\splitcell[l]{Mean Age at \\ Pathologic \\ Diagnosis} & 54.8 & 51.6 & 55.1 & 0.47* \\

\addlinespace

Ethnicity &  &  &  & 1.00\textsuperscript{\#} \\

\quad Caucasian        & 76 &
 \splitcell{6 \\ (55\%)} & \splitcell{52 \\ (57\%)} & \\

\quad \splitcell[l]{African \\ American} & 45 &
 \splitcell{4 \\ (36\%)} & \splitcell{30 \\ (33\%)} & \\

\quad NA               & 11 &
 \splitcell{1 \\ (9\%)}  & \splitcell{10 \\ (11\%)} & \\

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{%
  \parbox{0.8\textwidth}{\centering sfkdjkjke: lkjdfkljkljflasf; 
  ioawejroias: kjskldfj.asdjf.; pval:~p-value; *:~Wilcoxon test; 
  \textsuperscript{\#}:~Fisher's Exact Test; NA:~missing data}}\\
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Don't overuse `tabularx`. Also, try `\small` instead of `\footnotesize`; if it fits it makes for a more readable output.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `makecell`, `threeparttable` and `siunitx` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            makecell,                   % new
            tabularx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex} % new
\usepackage{siunitx}                    % new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]  
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Characteristics of Patients}
    \label{tab:ptChar}
\small
    \sisetup{input-comparators=<>,
             input-symbols = {( )},
             table-space-text-pre={(},
             table-space-text-post={\#},
             table-align-text-post=false}
    \setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright}X 
                        *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]}
                             S[table-format=1.2]
                             @{}}
    \toprule
Characteristic  &   {\makecell[t]{Patients\\ (n=132)}} 
                    &   {\makecell[t]{\SI{> 30}{\%}\\ (n=11)}} 
                        &   {\makecell[t]{\SI{< 30}{\%}\\ (n=92)}} 
                            &   {p value}\\
    \midrule
Mean Age at Pathologic Diagnosis 
    & 54.8  & 51.6      & 55.1      & 0.47\tnote{*}     \\
    \addlinespace 
Ethnicity 
    &       &           &           & 1.00\tnote{\#}    \\
\quad   Caucasian        
    & 76    & 6         & 52        &                   \\
    &       & (55\,\%)  & (57\,\%)  &                   \\
\quad   African American 
    & 45    & 4         & 30        &                   \\
    &       & (36\,\%)  & (33\,\%)  &                   \\
\quad   NA  
    & 11    & 1         & 10        &                   \\
    &       & (9\,\%)   & (91\,\%)  &                   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para]\centering
\note lkjdfkljkljflasf; ioawejroias: kjskldfj.asdjf.; NA:   missing data\\
       p-values:
       \item[*]:    Wilcoxon test,
       \item[\#]:   Fisher's Exact Test,    
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is unnecessary to start a table-environment with `\noindent`. I also suggest you remove the side bearings to the left and right of you tabular.

You can use nested tabular inside the last multicolumn. The multicolumn shall have the full width of the table and be centred. I use a fixed width `wc` column. The nested table has one columns `0.8\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,array,multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]  %% <-- Remove \noindent
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Characteristics of Patients\label{tab:ptChar}}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}P{0.15\textwidth}
                             >{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}X 
                             >{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}X
                             >{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}X
                             >{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
Characteristic & Patients (n=132) & $>$30\% (n=11) & $<$30\% (n=92) & p \\
\midrule

\raggedright Mean Age at Pathologic Diagnosis & 54.8 & 51.6 & 55.1 & 0.47* \\

\raggedright Ethnicity &  &  &  & 1.00\textsuperscript{\#} \\

\raggedright \hangindent=3mm \hangafter=0 Caucasian        & 76 &
 \shortstack{6 \\ (55\%)} & \shortstack{52 \\ (57\%)} & \\

\raggedright \hangindent=3mm \hangafter=0 African American & 45 &
 \shortstack{4 \\ (36\%)} & \shortstack{30 \\ (33\%)} & \\

\raggedright \hangindent=3mm \hangafter=0 NA               & 11 &
 \shortstack{1 \\ (9\%)}  & \shortstack{10 \\ (11\%)} & \\

\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\multicolumn{5}{wc{\linewidth}}{\begin{tabular}{@{}P{0.8\linewidth}@{}}
sfkdjkjke: lkjdfkljkljflasf; ioawejroias: kjskldfj.asdjf.; pval: p-value; *:~Wilcoxon test; \textsuperscript{\#}:~Fisher's Exact Test; NA:~missing data\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```